# Changing size of generic list classes

Tags: c#, arrays, class, generics, size

I have a .Net C# Classes like below. I want to add another Zones element like Zones.Add(xxx). As an example if I have an array of List int Zones, I would add a new element such as Zones.Add(5). How can I achieve this on a class?

Thanks

```
  public class Main : MonoBehaviour 
{
        [System.Serializable]
        public class arrayData
        {
            [System.Serializable]
            public class arrayData2
            {
            }
            public List<arrayData2> Levels;
        }
        public List<arrayData> Zones; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's really clear what you are asking. If you've got a `Zones` field then why can't you just say `myObj.Zones.Add(5)` ? Also, why add `5` anyway since your `Zones` field is of type `arrayData` ?

Comment: It was an example as if I had an int array. But I have a class array with another class inside. I could say Zones.Add(Zones) but it wouldn't work. Maybe I thought I can create a class like a simple Zones class like that: 
 public class arrayData
        {
....
        }     And then add it to the Zones.Add(arrayData) but it didnt work either. However I cna use Zones.RemoveAt(0). It should be very simple but i couldnt figure out how to add a new Class to that Zones class array